# Resolving a native Node module dependency in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, webpack, commonjs

I'm using [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) to play around with a library that connects with the Discogs API called [disconnect](https://github.com/bartve/disconnect). All is bundling nicely until I start to use a few choices methods from the disconnect library. It turns out that some of the modules the library uses are native Node modules, and the library does not officially support client-side JS environments.

***But***, I have a hunch that it's not doing anything that requires the Node environment; and I'm keen to get as far as I can on the client-side before giving up. One of the dependencies that is choking my experiment is a native Node module called [querystring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/querystring) (environment-agnostic as far as I can tell). This module is being required by *disconnect*, but not listed in *disconnect*'s *package.json* as it expects to be running in a Node environment where *querystring* is natively available.

What I want to do is have Webpack bundle Node's native *querystring* module such that my dependency *disconnect* can go ahead and use it.

For those who want to get stuck in, the specific error I'm getting in the browser is:

> Uncaught TypeError: queryString.escape is not a function
>       at Object.util.escape (util.js:38)
>       at Object.collection.getReleases (collection.js:87)
>       at eval (app.js:14)
>       at Object. (app.js:47)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>       at app.js:40
>       at app.js:43

My **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "some-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/js/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run clean && npm run build:html && npm run build:webpack-development",
    "pro": "npm run clean && npm run build:html && npm run build:webpack-production",
    "clean": "rm -rf build",
    "build:webpack-development": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --color --display-modules",
    "build:webpack-production": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --color",
    "build:html": "mkdir -p build && cp -f src/index.html build/index.html"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-livereload-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "disconnect": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

My **webpack.config.js**:

```
var path = require('path')

var LiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-livereload-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

var dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"

module.exports = {
  devtool: dev ? 'eval' : false,
  watch: dev,
  entry: {
    app: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js/app.js")
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/js"),
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.json$/, 
        loader: "json-loader" 
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js"),
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: ['es2015', 'es2016']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/sass"), 
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },
  plugins: [
    new LiveReloadPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("../css/app.css")
  ]
}
```

My **src/js/app.js**:

```
import * as disconnect from 'disconnect'

let Discogs = disconnect.Client

var col = new Discogs().user().collection();
col.getReleases('some-user', 0, {page: 2, per_page: 75}, function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Build with `npm install && npm run dev`.

Comment: You're in luck. Someone has written a generic node-compatible querystring module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/querystring. You may have to fork the library you're using. Or if it's in active development you may even want to submit a pull request to remove the node dependency.

Comment: @slebetman As you can probably see from my package.json, I am already requiring that library in the hope that webpack will expose it to my disconnect dependency. But that isn't happening. Is there really no way to provide an existing dependency with the dependency it needs via webpack?

Comment: @shennan have you found a solution?